# HTML automatically go back to previous page

Tags: html

How do I make the html go back to previous page?
I do not want to do it via a button, just that when this html gets loaded, it should automatically go back to previous page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL='>
      </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options. JavaScript or HTML Meta Tags.

A JavaScript example would be

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { 
   history.go(-1); 
});
```

Or using HTML Meta Tags like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://example.net">
```

Hope it helps! Be aware that this behaviour is, generally, not expected by the user, and could cause confusion

Comment: hey thanks! I do have a question, why do I have to provide a URL in the HTML tag? I was hoping I could use history.back() there. Is that possible?

Comment: You can pick between these two options, either one will work, the JavaScript or the HTML tag. I suggest using javascript

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna use the `history.back()` method that looks up at your history and send you back to the last visited website.